# What do you do if on thonny the buttons are are grey and do not work

Tags: thonny

I was trying to make a counter in python code and I went to the python interpreter Thonny and the buttons were grey and were not working. The last time I used it I was using microbit and it said error 22, maybe the microbit did something because of the error, but I don't know.

### I tried opening the Thonny with code saved and at the top there were some buttons saying: 'Step Over, Step into (f7), Step Out, and Resume (f8)' Then after that I tried deleting the code or opening a new file but the buttons went grey again. I was expecting better.
Also the shell said: "INTERNAL ERROR, got '' instead of 'OK'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\cpython_frontend\cp_front.py", line 39, in **init**
self._send_msg(ToplevelCommand("get_environment_info"))
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\running.py", line 1146, in _send_msg
self._proc.stdin.write(serialize_message(msg) + "\n")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\cpython_backend\cp_launcher.py", line 42, in 
from thonny import report_time
ImportError: cannot import name 'report_time' from 'thonny' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\thonny_*init*_.py)

Process ended with exit code 1."